# Can Automator or Applescript copy the number of items in a folder to the clipboard?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, automator

In Automator or Applescript, is there a way to get the number items in a folder and save result to the Clipboard or Automator Variable so I can use it in the next Action?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example, that also work if the folder is empty (return 0):

[image: Get Folder content]

The first shell script is :

> wc -l

The second is :

> sed -e 's/ //g'

The first script counts the number of lines and the second removes unnecessary spaces.

Comment: you can also use the command "pbcopy" for writing into the clipboard menu.

Comment: this is really nice. if only the loop action could take a variable...

Answer (score 0):

In AppleScript:

```
local nitems
tell application "Finder" to set nitems to count of items in folder "mress HD:Users:allbery:Desktop"
set the clipboard to (nitems as Unicode text)
```

Finder still uses Carbon-style paths, as shown above; to convert requires something silly like

```
local nitems
local fpath
tell application "System Events" to set fpath to path of disk item "/Users/allbery/Desktop"
tell application "Finder" to set nitems to count of items in folder fpath
set the clipboard to (nitems as Unicode text)
```

Comment: You could instead use `tell application "Finder" to set nitems to count of items in folder (POSIX file "/Users/danielbeck/Desktop")`

Comment: Hm, I thought I'd tried that and it whined at me about an illegal attribute.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Didn't even have to use `as alias`, as I came to expect.

Answer (score 0):

In just Applescript:

```
-- set fold to choose folder
tell app "Finder"
    set sel to selection
    set fold to item 1 of sel
    set n to count fold -- count items of entire contents of fold
end tell
-- set the clipboard to n as text
-- display dialog n
```